# Update With Inner Join throwing SQL command not properly ended error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables.

**DEPARTMENT** (TABLE)

```
DEPTID NUMBER(38)
NAME CHAR(20)
RANK NUMBER(38)
```

**EMPLOYEE** (TABLE)

```
EMPID NUMBER(38)
DEPTID NUMBER(38)
NAME CHAR(40)
AGE NUMBER(38)
SALARY NUMBER(38)
```

And I am trying to run following query, which is continuously throwing error.
The query is to update Rank in Department table based on the Average age of employees in every department.

```
UPDATE d 
SET d.rank = T.rank 
FROM  department d
INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT
          rownum as rank, age, deptId 
      FROM 
          (SELECT 
               AVG(age) AS age, deptid 
           FROM employee
           GROUP by deptId
           ORDER BY age DESC)) AS T ON T.deptId = d.deptId;
```

Comment: not exactly duplication, since the question stops at ORA-01779 problem, and how to solve this issue.

Comment: There may be duplicates of this question, but I don't think that the one chosen would help the OP solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of [UPDATE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10008.htm#SQLRF01708) statement in Oracle does not support joins.
A [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9017.htm#SQLRF01606) statement can be used to do this task:

```
MERGE INTO DEPARTMENT d
USING (
     SELECT
             rownum as rank, age, deptId 
     FROM 
       (SELECT AVG(age) AS age, deptid 
        FROM employee
        GROUP by deptId
        ORDER BY age DESC)
) q
ON ( d.DEPTID = q.DEPTID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET d.RANK = q.rank
```

A working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f0f34/2

Comment: Thanks krokodilko, I was writing exact same solution for my problem as you mentioned above. but, for some reason, it was giving me 0 results.